# Why create a fake duplicate / clone website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, duplicate-content, google-analytics-spam

Here is my problem...
Someone created an exact copy of my website, including my Analytics and Adsense codes and started sending traffic to this fake site around 100k+ visitors a day.

Does anyone know, what is the reason for doing such a nonsense thing?

Comment: You want to know what is the reason of this or how to resolve your issue?

Comment: What is the reason of this? How can it influence on my wwebsite?

Comment: How do you know that clone site is getting 100k visitors a day?

Comment: Cause they left my Analytic and Adsense codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...what is the reason for doing such a nonsense thing?

They might...

- be associated with a competitor and want to take traffic away from your site. An exact clone of your site on another domain can only be detrimental to your sites SEO.
- be trying to increase the value of their domain (an established site that receives lots of traffic), which they can then later sell on for a profit. Your site is just an unfortunate pawn in the process, selected because of its popularity.
- be trying to serve malware to unsuspecting visitors by injecting malicious links/code into the cloned site. (Since the cloned site is relatively easy to setup and appears to be attracting a large number of visitors.)

It can also depend on the website, how it is being cloned and modified. They might also:

- profit from changing the advertising network to one of their own.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is report that website to google and other authorities
secondly you should create a filter in google analytics that includes hits from only your hostname

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Spammers have different purpose for doing that, but I will recommended these things.

1. Report that website to Google for duplicate content.
2. Block that website in your adsense dashboard, so the earning and fake clicks or any other invalid activity will not count.
3. Use filter in Google analytics, if you think you can't see
   reports very well.

The reason may be various, it's depend on which kind of spammer is, I mean noob or advance.

Some of noob, just send bot traffic in order to block your adsense, or damage your seo, but it will not going to help them. Since you can block and report that kind of things.

Some of noob, just scrape your website content, and drive traffic and sell it to flippa or any other marketplace.

For advance spammer I have no idea, but you should really check their activity. Their main purpose is only benefits. I have seen some of website (normally porn) is blocked in some of country, so some of spammer take that advantages and clone the blocked website in order to get visitors and monetize later from advertising. It can be various reason, since your website is adsense ready, so that might be not problem for you, **but you should check their activity regularly.**

Comment: How can I block their website in adsense? Any directions? Thank you!

Comment: Found an answer to my question, if someone's interested: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65062